# unable to access Apache Tomcat server on WIndows Server 2003 externally

Tags: windows-server-2003, tomcat

I am running Apache Tomcat 8.0.21 on Windows Server 2003.
I have set the connector port to 3001. I am able to access Apache Tomcat server sitting on the machine where server is installed through localhost:3001. In addition to it, I have set the Connector address to "0.0.0.0" so that it can be access from any IP address. But I am unable to access it from some external source.

From the Telnet response, I can say that the port 3001 is open and accessible from external source.

I have pasted below the server.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />

<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />  
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

<GlobalNamingResources>
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
          description="User database that can be updated and saved"
          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
</GlobalNamingResources>

<Service name="Catalina">

<Connector port="3001" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
           address="0.0.0.0" 
            useIPVHosts="true"/>

<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />

<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">

    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  </Realm>


<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps"
    unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
    xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

  </Host>
</Engine>
</Service>
</Server>
```

Kindly tell me what am I missing or doing wrong?
And I want to thank you, in advance, for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to solve this issue.
I was using **proxy-server** which **was causing the problem**.
Created an exception for my server IP (where the tomcat application resides), to not use proxy-server and ALL Worked!